# Swift - Navigation, Back, Custom destination

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, back

If I want to change the destination of a back button in the navigation bar. How can I accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: depends on what exactly you want to go. U can set a custom navigationController and implement its delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it as is, but you can use the following method

```
func setViewControllers(viewControllers: [AnyObject]!, animated: Bool)
```

Instead of just `push` new `viewController` you set a new array then back button will navigate to the `viewController` that is last but one in the current stack